# Getting "all" itineraries for a specific timeframe out of OpenTripPlanner in a single request

Tags: transit, opentripplanner

Following the [tutorial](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/dev-2.x/Basic-Tutorial/) I set up an OpenTripPlanner 2.0.0 server with the Portland area for routing requests. Now I would like to compile a collection of many possible itineraries.

By default I get around 3-4 itineraries by request. E. g. http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=45.51789504294005%2C-122.52365112304688&toPlace=45.49575902279182%2C-122.61772155761719&time=7%3A35pm&date=07-23-2021&mode=TRANSIT%2CWALK&maxWalkDistance=4828.032&arriveBy=false&wheelchair=false&debugItineraryFilter=false&locale=en as requested by the browser when using the example GUI will return 3 alternative itineraries.

How can I make OpenTripPlanner return all suitable itineraries for a whole day?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `searchWindow=86400` parameter (in seconds) to include all itineraries that falls within that time window (in your case 24H*3600s = 86400)

Comment: Thank you, I had forgotten to post my own solution back then. In the end I used     `searchWindow=86400&numOfItineraries=99999&keepNumOfItineraries=99999` and hoped for the best.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add the parameter `&numItineraries=x` (where `x` is an integer) to your request URL to specify the maximum number of route options to return. Note that this sets the maximum, if there are less options, you will get fewer routes than specified here.

So if you for example want to return 7 options, your URL will look like this:

http://localhost:8080/otp/routers/default/plan?fromPlace=45.51789504294005%2C-122.52365112304688&toPlace=45.49575902279182%2C-122.61772155761719&time=7%3A35pm&date=07-23-2021&mode=TRANSIT%2CWALK&maxWalkDistance=4828.032&arriveBy=false&wheelchair=false&debugItineraryFilter=false&locale=en&numItineraries=7

If you want all trips for a whole day by `TRANSIT,WALK` I suggest to fire several requests (e.g. in a loop) with different `&time` parameters instead of using a very high number of itineraries.

Comment: Thank you! That parameter worked sometimes for me, but seems not really strict. I updated the question to specify that I really want all suitable itineraries within a timeframe. Doing multiple requests is big overhead, most probably for the router too, so it is not an option for me.